# How to stop a running timeline in GameMaker Studio?

Tags: game-maker

I am creating a game using GameMaker Studio and I need to stop a timeline that is in progress. How can I approach that with GML code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
timeline_running = false;
```

or

```
timeline_speed = 0;
```